# Form view in odoo 12

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

In my custom module, there is one relation field. After click on create and edit form view is pop up. But I didn’t want to open this form view as a popup. I want to open this form view in the current window or in the current form. This is possible in odoo 12 or by using javascript Please, anyone, help me. 
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Model and view are defined as per odoo instruction as :

```
class SurveySurvey(models.Model):
    _name = 'survey.survey'

    pages_ids = fields.One2many('survey.page','survey_id', string='Pages', copy=True)
```

View:

```
<field name="pages_ids" mode="tree" context="{'default_survey_id': active_id}" options="{'no_open':False}">
    <tree editable="bottom" > 
       <field name="title"/>
       <field name="question_ids" class="question_ids_class" widget="many2many_tags" context="{'page_id': active_id}" domain="[('page_id','=','active_id')]" options="{'no_open':true,'no_quick_create':true}"/>
     </tree>   
</field>
```

question_id is a relation field after click on **create and edit** option available in relation field one popup is open javascript code for that pop is as follows:

```
_searchCreatePopup: function (view, ids, context) {
        var self = this;
        return new dialogs.SelectCreateDialog(this, _.extend({}, this.nodeOptions, {
            res_model: this.field.relation,
            domain: this.record.getDomain({fieldName: this.name}),
            context: _.extend({}, this.record.getContext(this.recordParams), context || {}),
            title: (view === 'search' ? _t("Search: ") : _t("Create: ")) + this.string,
            initial_ids: ids ? _.map(ids, function (x) { return x[0]; }) : undefined,
            initial_view: view,
            disable_multiple_selection: true,
            no_create: !self.can_create,
            on_selected: function (records) {
                self.reinitialize(records[0]);
                self.activate();
            }
        })).open();
    },
```

The above code is available in web/static/js/fields/relational_fields.js
For better understanding please see screenshots.

[image]

Screenshot after click on Create and  edit
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some code of your model and view.

Comment: Thanks, @lne-io for your replay. I have edited my question can you please check.

Comment: You have to override the default formview or you can create a custom widget that will open the custom view on your button click.

Comment: But after creating a custom form view is it possible to open in already exiting the form. I am not using a button I want to do this in relational field create and edit option.